# Enhancing performance of matrix transformation in R

Tags: r, matrix, transformation

I have a little problem with a fast matrix transformation. That transformation has to be performed a lot of times, so I'm looking for a fast way to this. Imagine a given matrix `A` and a integer parameter `L`. Matrix `A` should be transformed into a new matrix `newA` with `L` rows and `nrow(A)*ncol(A)/L` columns. I take `L` rows of `A` and want to transform them into columns. A little example with two possible solutions to this problem `newA1` and `newA2` where `newA1 = newA2` should clarify my explanations:

```
A = matrix(1:24,6,4,byrow=T)  #example matrix
L = 2  #number of rows for new matrix
newA1 = NULL
newA2 = matrix(0,L,nrow(A)*ncol(A)/L)
for(i in 1:(nrow(A)/L)){
 newA1 = cbind(newA1,A[((i-1)*L+1):(i*L),])      #slower than newA2
 newA2[1:L,((i-1)*ncol(A)+1):(i*ncol(A))] = A[((i-1)*L+1):(i*L),]  #faster than newA1
}
```

The matrices look like that:

```
> A
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
  [1,]    1    2    3    4
  [2,]    5    6    7    8
  [3,]    9   10   11   12
  [4,]   13   14   15   16
  [5,]   17   18   19   20
  [6,]   21   22   23   24
> newA1
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
  [1,]    1    2    3    4    9   10   11   12   17    18    19    20
  [2,]    5    6    7    8   13   14   15   16   21    22    23    24
```

`L=3` works also in this example.

Comment: I wonder if this is any better `matrix(unlist(split(A, rep(1:(nrow(A)/L), each = L))), L, length(A)/L)`

Comment: Thanks, it works! It seems a little faster than `newA1`. In `newA2` I found a mistake when I take other matrices than in my example. I will try to fix this and then edit my question.

Comment: Ok, no mistake in my code. For big matrices I tried `identical(newA1,newA2)` and it was FALSE. The reason is, that R uses data type "int" for `newA1` and your solution and "num" for `newA2`. Because of this, the `newA2` matrix is larger in terms of memory use. The advantage is nevertheless that the solution for `newA2` is about 10 times faster than yours. But in fact, your solution outperforms `newA1`.

Comment: Maybe utilizing your second method you could try `matrix(sapply(1:(nrow(A)/L), function(i) A[((i-1)*L+1):(i*L),]),  L, length(A)/L)`? This gives me an integer matrix, and also avoids intermediate assignments

Comment: @David Thanks! It performs just slightly worse than `newA2` but takes just half the amount of memory. This solution will definitely be considered!

Comment: How many times do you need to repeat this?

Comment: I need to run this 1000 times as a sub routine of my algorithm on 400 test problems.

Comment: 1000 times on matrices of same dimensions or the dimensions can be varied on each independent run?

Comment: The matrices must have 1000 times the same dimensions. The elements differ in each iteration.